# How to handle associations between records in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### Explanation:

Working with ember-data, a lot of different scenarios pop up that don't all seem to match the way the internals work at this point. First off, some data:

```
{ "post":
  {
    "id": "60",
    "title": "Hello, Stack Overflow friends!",
    "comments": []
  }
}
```

Say the above is data from the database.

Then, a `post` record is fetched **on client 1 and client 2** by calling `post = App.Post.find(60)` on each client, respectively. So far, they both have the same `post` record - loaded with an empty `comments` array.

At a later time, a comment is created **on client 2**. This is done by calling `comment = App.Comment.createRecord({text: "Why, hello there.", post: post})`.

The comment data is then saved server-side, looking like so:

```
{ "comment":
  {
    "id": "80",
    "text": "Why, hello there.",
    "post_id": "60"
  }
}
```

At this point, **client 2 is up-to-date** - since this is where the comment was created - but **client 1 is out-of-sync**, because it does not know of the new comment.

Now, client 1 may become aware of the newly created comment one way or another (via XHR or WS).

Once client 1 knows the id, a `comment` record is fetched by calling `comment = App.Comment.find(80)`.

... Yet calling `post.get('comments')` **on client 1** results in 0 comments. Even though the new comment was fetched successfully, no association between the `comment` and the `post` was made.

### Problem:

- When fetching the comment on client 1, no auto-association magic is happening to associate the `comment` record with the `post` record.

Note 1: this does not happen because on client 1, the `post` record was originally loaded with `comments: []`. If the array had contained the comment id, `80`, this would have worked (besides the fact that the comment did not exist at load time).

Note 2: I can add the association manually by calling `post.get('comments').addObject(comment)` on client 1, but this dirties the `post` record and doesn't seem like a proper way of handling this.

### Question:

- Is there a way to somehow create the association between the `post` and `comment` records on client 1 that does not involve using `addObject` or any similar functions that dirties the `post` record?

Comment: did you resolve this and are you happy to post back here, how it was resolved. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you load a record that has a `belongsTo` relationship, ember data doesn't currently update the "parent" record of the relationship.

One way to solve this problem in your case is to sideload the "parent" record. In your case, you would send (via XHR or WS) the `comment` and the `post`.

There's an open ticket for this problem https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/695